# LWC Creating and displaying nested list from a Map<string, list<class>>

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a nested list of deliverables due to colleges for display via a lightning web component. I am doing some pre-processing in my controller, so the output data is a map with key of College Name, and then a list of a public custom class containing the data I'd like displayed in the detail lines.

Here is the Apex Controller:

```java
public without sharing class CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static map<string,list<Deliverable>> getDeliverables(string TimeFrame){
        map<string,list<Deliverable>> Deliverables = new map<string,list<Deliverable>>();
        list<Statement_of_Work__c> SOWS = getRecords(TimeFrame);
        
        String currentFiscalYear = [SELECT FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate <= TODAY AND EndDate >= TODAY].FiscalYearSettings.Name;
                
        for(Statement_of_Work__c SOW: SOWS){
            for(sow_line_item__c SOWLI: SOW.sow_line_items__r){
                deliverable d = new deliverable();
                d.name = SOWLI.Title__c != null ? SOWLI.Title__c : SOWLI.Coach_Deliverables__r.Name;
                d.Status = SOWLI.Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c == 0 ? 'Fulfilled' : 'Open';
                d.ExpectedDate = SOWLI.Estimated_Completion_Date__c;
                d.SOWLIId = SOWLI.id;
                d.FulfillmentLink = SOWLI.fulfillment_link__c;
                d.Description = SOWLI.description__c; 
                
                string MapKey = SOW.College__c != null ? SOW.College__c : 'Internal';
                if(SOWLI.Year__c != currentFiscalYear){
                    MapKey += ' - ' + SOWLI.Year__c;
                }
                if(deliverables.containskey(MapKey)){
                    deliverables.get(MapKey).add(d);
                } else {
                    list<deliverable> Dlist = new list<deliverable>();
                    Dlist.add(d);
                    deliverables.put(MapKey,Dlist);
                }
                
            }
        }
        return Deliverables;
    }
    public static list<Statement_of_Work__c> getRecords(string TimeFrame){
        String currentFiscalYear = [SELECT FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate <= TODAY AND EndDate >= TODAY].FiscalYearSettings.Name;
        String SOWLIConditions = '';
        User u = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        string CoachContactId = '0035500001OE30eAAD'; 
        //string CoachContactId = u.contactId;
        system.debug(CoachContactId);
        if(TimeFrame == 'Current'){
            SOWLIConditions = ' Year__c = \'' + currentFiscalYear + '\' or Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c > 0 ';
        } else {
            SOWLIConditions = ' Year__c < \'' + currentFiscalYear + '\'';
        }
        string SOWQuery = 'Select Id, Name, College__c, (Select Id, Name, Type__c, Fulfillment_Link__c, Estimated_Completion_Date__c, description__c, Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c, title__c, coach_deliverables__r.name, Year__c From SOW_Line_Items__r where '+ SOWLIConditions + ') from Statement_of_Work__c ';
        SOWQuery += 'where Contractor_Contact__c = \'' + CoachContactId + '\' and ';
        SOWQuery += 'id in (select statement_of_work__c from SOW_Line_Item__c where '+ SOWLIConditions + ')';
        SOWQuery += ' and status__c = \'Accepted\' ';
        SOWQuery +='order by Institution__r.name asc';
        list<Statement_of_Work__c> SOWS =  Database.query(SOWQuery);
        
        system.debug(SOWQuery);
        return SOWS;
    }
    public class Deliverable{
        public string name;
        public string status;
        public date expectedDate;
        public string SOWLIId;
        public string fulfillmentLink;
        public string description; 
    }
}
```

When I test this with an execute anonymous, it looks as intended:

```
{Test Coach Organization In Network=(Deliverable:[SOWLIId=a1d55000002TZc5AAG, description=During a Virtual Visit, Consultant will conduct virtual meetings in person for a minimum of 1.0 hours., expectedDate=null, fulfillmentLink=<a href="linkformula" target="_blank">Click to Submit</a>, name=Custom Virtual Visit w/o SVR - 1.0 hours, status=Open], Deliverable:[SOWLIId=a1d55000002VK8QAAW, description=Additional hour/s provided to conduct pre-visit preparationand the c
```

I have tried all manner of online advice in my lwc js file so it is a hot mess at this point, representing my last failure more than anything else. I'll add the html file below as well, though I think it's fine as far as it goes.

When I console log the stringified json (line 16), it has the correct number of list items , but they all appear to be blank, so I'm not sure the data is even reaching the LWC intact.

```
{"Test Coach Organization In Network":[{},{},{}]}
```

The html output has a line for the map key "Test Coach Organization in Network", then three blank lines representing the three sub items. Thanks for any hints you can give me - I've spent a lot of time at this dead end.

**.js file**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.getDeliverables';
export default class CPAssignmentList extends LightningElement {
    
    @api TimeFrame;
    displaydata = false;
    deliverables=[];

    @wire(getRecords, {       
        TimeFrame: "$TimeFrame"
    }) 
    getResults(result){
        console.log(result.data);
        if(result.data){
            var conts = result.data;
            var str = JSON.stringify(conts);
            console.log(str);
            for(var key in conts){
                this.subarraylist = [];
                for( var item in conts[key]){
                    this.deliverable = conts[key][item];
                                       
                    this.subarray = [];
                    
                    for(var subkey in this.deliverable){
                        subarray.push({value:deliverable[subkey], key:subkey});
                        console.log(subkey);
                    }
                    this.subarraylist.push(this.subarray);
                }
                
                this.deliverables.push({value:this.subarraylist, key:key}); //Here we are creating the top level array to show on UI.
                console.log(key);
                this.displaydata = true;
            }
        }else{
            console.log('Error');
        }

    }
}
```

**.html file**

```html
<template>
    <template if:false={displaydata}>
        <strong>You have no current assignments to fulfill</strong>
    </template>
    <template if:true={displaydata}>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th>Institution</th>
                    <th>Fulfillment</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Expected Completion</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>         
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={deliverables} for:item="sow">
                    <tr class="sowHeaderRow" key ={sow.key}>
                        <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="4">
                           {sow.key}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <template for:each={sow.value} for:item="sowli"> 
                        <tr class="sowliHeaderRow" key ={sowli.SOWLIId}>   
                            <td class="spacer">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                               {sowli.status}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span title='{sowli.description}'>{sowli.Name}</span> 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {sowli.ExpectedDate}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>

                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to expose a property of a custom Apex class to LWC, it must be annotated with [`@AuraEnabled`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-wire-method.html), so you have to change your `Deliverable` class to:

```java
public class Deliverable{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String status;

    @AuraEnabled
    public Date expectedDate;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String SOWLIId;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String fulfillmentLink;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String description; 
}
```

In `getResults` method in JS, you mixed instance and local variable: you defined `this.subarray` (instance variable) but then you used `subarray.push` without this, so a local one, which was never defined, thus it throws an exception since you cannot call push on `undefined`. Moreover, looking at the HTML code, you don't need (you don't use) `subarray`.
As a thumb rule, use local variable when possible and define an instance one only if strictly needed.
I would also suggest to prefer [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) over `var`. `let` and `const` are block scoped and [non-hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

The `getResults` method should look like:

```js
@wire(getRecords, { TimeFrame: "$TimeFrame" }) 
getResults(result) {
    console.log(result.data);
    if (result.data) {
        const deliverableMap = result.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(deliverableMap));
        for (const key in deliverableMap) {
            this.deliverables.push({value: deliverableMap[key], key}); //Here we are creating the top level array to show on UI.
            console.log(key);
        }
        this.displaydata = true;
    } else {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that Javascript is case-sensitive, so since in the `Deliverable` class there is a property `name`, if in the template you refer to it using `Name`, it won't work. The same goes for `expectedDate` vs `ExpectedDate`. That's why the HTML should be changed to:

```html
<template for:each={sow.value} for:item="sowli"> 
    <tr class="sowliHeaderRow" key ={sowli.SOWLIId}>   
        <td class="spacer">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
           {sowli.status}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span title="{sowli.description}">{sowli.name}</span> 
        </td>
        <td>
            {sowli.expectedDate}
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Please note that `if:true` and `if:false` have been deprecated. You should use [`lwc:if|elseif|else`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html) instead.

```html
<template lwc:if={displaydata}>
<!-- the table -->
</template>
<template lwc:else>
    <strong>You have no current assignments to fulfill</strong>
</template>
```

Please be consistent with your naming convention. I would suggest following Java one, as stated in [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_naming_conventions.htm), so classes (like `String`, `List`, `Date`, etc...) should start with a capital letter, while methods and variable names should start with a lowercase one.

Comment: Thank you - you got me past this hurdle and the next couple as well. I very much appreciate the assistance.